# How to check the program/applicationname that triggered function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

There are two applications that used the same function (trigger) in postgresql. I have to ignore notification by applicatonname. How do I identify the current program/application that called the function?

Comment: You can only do that _if_ the applications comply and actually set the application name e.g. through `set application_name  =...`. Then you can retrieve it using `current_setting()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you make your comment an Answer so this Question can be closed?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name application_name can also be set as part of the connection string.(or jdbc resurce locator etc) thus applications that can use a connection string can be forced to set application_name

Answer (score 4):

You can use `select current_setting('application_name');` but I've seen instances of client program (not written by me) not giving application name after a connection reset. You should also see comment from @a_horse_with_no_name above.